# functions with different names but same arguments

Tags: c++, macros

I have a set of functions with the same number of arguments, but different names (suppose each implement different method). I have the name of the requested method in a string. Is it possible to call the corresponding function using the method name. to make it clear, suppose that I have the following function (I just mentioned their name and argument):

```
search_esa(int a, int b);
search_tss(int a, int b);
search_fss(int a, int b);
search_ds(int a, int b);
```

now lets assume I have the name of the requested method, lets assume esa, in a string:

```
string methodName = "esa"
```

is it possible to call the corresponding function by using macros?
I tested

```
#define CALL_SEARCH_MV(method) search_##method
```

and then try to call it by:

```
CALL_SEARCH_MV(methodName.c_str())
```

but it calls search_methodName function, which does not exist. Any other suggestions would be greatly appreciated (except suggesting switch case method or if).

Comment: Use a [map](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/unordered_map)?

Comment: Specifically, function pointers in a map!

Comment: And just to answer one of your questions: No it's not possible to do using macros. Macros are a compile-time thing, like templates, and `methodName.c_str()` is a run-time thing.

Comment: You can use a combination of Macros, function pointers and clever hacking to achieve the desired result with ease. I'm writing up an answer detailing how.

Comment: How about if(methodName == "esa") search_esa(...). Really if you have 5 functions why bother using function pointers and maps? Even switch will do

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a combination of Macros, function pointers and clever hacking to achieve the desired result with ease.

**In your main.cpp (or where the search functionality lives):**

```
#include <map>
#include <string>
#include <iostream>

typedef int(*search)(int a, int b);

#define SEARCH(x) int search_##x(int a, int b);
#include "search_func.incl"
#undef SEARCH

#define SEARCH(x) {#x, search_##x},
std::map<std::string, search> search_funcs = {
#include "search_func.incl"    
};
#undef SEARCH


int main(char** argv, int argc)
{
    std::cout << search_funcs["esa"](1, 2) << std::endl;
    std::cout << search_funcs["tss"](3, 4) << std::endl;
    std::cout << search_funcs["fss"](5, 6) << std::endl;
    std::cout << search_funcs["ds"](7, 8) << std::endl;

    return 0;
}

int search_esa(int a, int b) { return 100 * a + 10 * b + 0; }
int search_tss(int a, int b) { return 100 * a + 10 * b + 1; }
int search_fss(int a, int b) { return 100 * a + 10 * b + 2; }
int search_ds(int a, int b) { return 100 * a + 10 * b + 3; }
```

**In search_func.incl**

```
SEARCH(esa)
SEARCH(tss)
SEARCH(fss)
SEARCH(ds)
```

**How this works**
The search_func.incl file specifies the name of your search functions with a macro. When you include the file, you switch up the definition of the macro so that the included functions are presented differently.

```
SEARCH(abc)
```

becomes a function declaration on the first include:

```
int search_abc(int a, int b);
```

and a key value pair {string, function pointer} on the second include:

```
{"abc", search_abc},
```

These KVP are in a map, so when  you need to call a function, the string maps to the function name automatically.

Comment: PS.: If anyone know what this trick is called, I'd love to know the name. It's very useful in game programming: you can have enums with int values but refer to them by name in game scripts.

Answer (score 4):

Something like this would probably work:

```
std::map<std::string, std::function<void(int, int)>> functions{
    {"esa", search_esa},
    {"tss", search_tss},
    {"fss", search_fss},
    {"ds", search_ds}
};

int main(int argc, char ** argv) {
    std::string cmd = argv[1];
    functions.at(cmd)(5, 10);
    return 0;
}
```

It's worth noting, though, that you can't really generalize this. If you added another function, like say, `search_rsa`, you'd have to manually add an entry for it to the map. C++ doesn't have the comprehensive reflection capabilities that a language like Java or Python has, so you can't just write a function that takes a string and searches for a method that has a name matching that string.

Comment: `std::function<void(int, int)>` might be replaced by `void (*)(int, int)` in case of OP (and avoid type erasure).

Answer (score 1):

You can store function pointers in containers. So you can map pretty much anything. The syntax is pretty simple:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <map>
using namespace std;

int f1(int a, int b) { return a+b; }
int f2(int a, int b) { return a*b; }

int main() {
    int x = 5;
    int y = 3;
    map<string, int(*)(int, int)> f;

    f["add"] = &f1;
    f["mul"] = &f2;

    cout << f["add"](x,y) << "\n";
    cout << f["mul"](x,y) << "\n";
    return 0;
}
```

Live: http://ideone.com/wLjw1i.

So you can store any function with matching signature (+return type). This is a the expense of one indirection. The means they are harder to be optimized, because the jump target is set in the run time.

You can make it a bit more general using `std::function`, again at slight performance expense.

Answer (score -1):

**Not Possible!**
the methods defined must be call with the same name. we cannot manipulate the method name.

Comment: Yes there are ways to associate functions with string, either at runtime or at compile-time. There is, however, no automatic construct in the language that do that for you.